# How to use partial match when using Mongo find javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The following line of javascript code finds all devices from a defined Mongo collection Devices with error codes 210 or 220

```
const devices = await Devices.find({"ErrorCode": { "$in": ["210", "220"] }});
```

How would I be able to retrieve all devices with ErrorCodes containing 210 or 220 as a substring. Consider a device with error code: "Error: 210". I also want to retrieve that device.

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated!

Sample Document:

```
{
    "DeviceId" : "1234567890",
    "Status" : "ONLINE",
    "ErrorMessage" : "Error Code: 220 Error Message: Duplicate found",
    "Code" : "Error Code: 220",
}
```

Comment: try using regular expression `{"ErrorCode": { "$in": [/210/, /220/] }}`

Comment: Given that the error codes are strings would that be `{"ErrorCode": { "$in": [/"210"/, /"220"/] }}` ?

Comment: no without double quotes, or second way try regular expression function, `{"ErrorCode": { "$in": [new RegExp("210"), new RegExp("220")] }}`

Comment: My way with double quotes didn't work. Didn't pick up any documents. But neither `{"ErrorCode": { "$in": [/"210"/, /"220"/] }}` or `{"ErrorCode": { "$in": [new RegExp("210"), new RegExp("220")] }}` didn't pick up the other document with error code looking like this "Error Code: 220". How would I be able to also find that one?

Comment: Maybe because the error code includes the character ":" ?

Comment: I found a different error. Once I resolved that `{"ErrorCode": { "$in": [new RegExp("210"), new RegExp("220")] }}` worked. Thanks @turivishal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regular expression, added 3 ways,

**1) `$regex` with `$or`:**

You can try `$regex` regular expression operator with `$or` condition

```
const devices = await Devices.find({
  $or: [
    { Code: { $regex: "210" } },
    { Code: { $regex: "220" } }
  ]
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BQIdXMKyg9V)

---

**2) `new RegExp`:**

```
const devices = await Devices.find({
  Code: {
    $in: [new RegExp("210"), new RegExp("220")]
  }
});
```

**3) `/` slash:**

```
const devices = await Devices.find({
  Code: {
    $in: [/210/, /220/] // without double quotes
  }
});
```